# SaltStack - Pass dpkg options to salt.states.pkg.uptodate

Tags: salt-stack, system-administration

I have a state in SaltStack which I use to update all system packages:

```
system_upgrade:
  pkg.uptodate:
    - refresh: true
    - order: last
```

However it happened that a new package was available (e.g. *php*) which had a new configuration file and *apt* was stuck asking interactively what the user would do with current configuration file (replace, keep, etc..). Of course it's a problem since *states.apply* runs in background so there must not be any interactive action.

Now I would avoid this on *apt* using

```
apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::='--force-confold' upgrade
```

but how can I do this in SaltStack?

Answer (score 0):

In [pkg.upgrade](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.aptpkg.html#salt.modules.aptpkg.upgrade) module you have, `force_conf_new` which allows you to force install the new version of any configuration files.

You can use it with `pkg.uptodate` as mentioned in docs,

[kwargs](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.pkg.html#salt.states.pkg.uptodate): Any keyword arguments to pass through to `pkg.upgrade`.